# Android sqlite multi table populate

Tags: android, sqlite, multi-table

I m working on Android SQLite. My problem is that How do **`I work with many sqlite tables`**, with which I have **`two activity`** being populated and layout with gridview and listview, each of these invoke different table.

Comment: ok now what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not the place to learn that. Did you read the [Android tutorial about using SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)? Do you know [what SQL is](http://www.sqlcourse.com/intro.html)? Read those first, then try to apply them, then come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score -1):

At first activity query 1 specific sqlite table and show in Listview while at other activity query second table and show in Gridview